# How to deal with botnets and automated submissions

Tags: security, spam-prevention

Short story: I have a web application that has a huge incentive for participation. As such, we're being targeted heavily by the scripters and bots. Based on the IP addresses the submissions are coming from (1000+ and growing, no pattern whatsoever), I'm inclined to believe the submissions are being generated by a bot network. Even worse, the person(s) controlling the automated submissions are actively persuing things to the point that every time we make a change, they catch up within a few hours.

Some of the measures we've tried already:

- Captcha, both third party and home-grown, with varying degrees of readability
- An anti-request forgery token sent via cookie and hidden form field that is compared upon submit
- A hidden empty honeypot field that causes the submission to fail silently if the field contains data
- A hidden honeypot field that contains data by default and results in a silent fail if a piece of javascript does not run to clear the field's value
- Limiting submissions by IP address over a certain time period
- Blocking email domains known to be used by the automated scripts
- Blocking hosts based on simultaneous connections or connections per minute at the firewall
- Blocking the most flagrant IP addresses at the firewall
- Using an external address verification service to verify incoming addresses

Even with all of these measures in place, the submissions have not only continued, but seem to be increasing in frequency, on the order of 100,000+ per day.

The bogus entries are now using completely valid first and last names, and apparently have resorted to using some sort of directory listing to ensure that the addresses they use (which appear totally random and not at all consistent, btw) are actually valid US postal addresses. Additionally, I have logged the incoming form values to a debug log and verified that they are actually submitting valid captcha codes, indicating they have OCR good enough to decipher the images (the code itself is never sent to the client, only a GUID representing a code that is stored elsewhere on the back end)

In fact, the only way we can even tell the entries are bogus is by the pattern of email addresses and domains they are submitting. We've tried blocking the most active domains from entering, but the spammers just create or find new domains from which they can generate disposable email addresses and keep on going.

I'm pretty exhausted at this point, but I'm sure there's got to be something I haven't tried. Does anyone here have any bright ideas?

Comment: Hah, that sounds bad. Is asking users to mail you for the "incentive" out of the question?

Comment: We're already discussing the option of having an admin step in to approve or deny the incentive prior to emailing the user, which should help some, but in the mean time, the numbers of entries on the reports keeps skyrocketing.

Comment: Hah, I meant snail mail. :D botnets be pwnt.

Comment: I don't believe they'll bypass http://www.solvemedia.com/ captcha.

Comment: Hi Chris, is this still a problem? If so, could we take this offline? I'd like to discuss something with you. Can you can contact me through my profile. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is: because of only 'registering' to your site, the user receives too many rights at once. The user is trusted "too fast".

Look at stackoverflow - you can register, and you gain almost no rights at the beginning. User permissions level increases after some time, because the trust to the user increases, because of what the user is doing, and other users accept that.

I would focus on making users "trust" a kind of "build-able resource" where other users have to confirm "authority level" of a particular user. Then auto-registering of users would make no meaning - they can do nothing.

I don't know what your site is about - that probably makes my suggestion not acceptable... But I hope I made your thoughts go forward :)

Comment: Indeed it does make your suggestion not acceptable, but not by your own fault. I'm hesitant to describe it too much, but suffice it to say it's an instant win promotion - you sign up, the program determines if you're a random instant winner, and you instantly receive a reward to be delivered via email.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a picture captcha, where you have a picture of a cup, for example, with C _ _ underneath? Tedious to spend a bunch of time creating a ton of images to implement it, but it'll really test their resolve to spend all that time manually identifying 1000 images. Of course, I don't know how good your prizes are, it might be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for an answer to your question - but have you considered validating the information the user has submit together? Like if you need them to put in their name, physical address, phone number, and email address, checking a phone directory or address book to make sure that all the information they've entered is consistent. That way you could validate an entry with more than just well formed data, but an actual person.

Another thing you could consider is sending the user a text message informing them that they've won, instead of doing it via email.

Not sure how appropriate it is for your case, but it might help.

Comment: We're still fighting with the issue, so any advice is still helpful. We're standardizing the user's address, and we've implemented a feature where the user has to click a link an an email to validate their email address before gaining an entry. The problem is that the persons responsible for the scripting are smart enough to a) harvest directories for valid address info and b) script the retrieval of the email validation link. They've gone so far as to set up anon domains on top of disposable email services and script hundreds of thousands of email accounts to use.

Comment: Suffice it to say, they're still getting through.

Comment: "we've implemented a feature where the user has to click a link an an email to validate their email address before gaining an entry" - this is easy to bypass if the "bad guy" parses your email with a script that navigates to the activation link automatically. You can implement a captcha on validation page that validates the validation link, sorry for the redundancy...